# how to pass reference id in model while importing excel file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby, rubygems

i am importing data from excel file into two different table based on `id` column in excel file. 
`project` has one_to_many association with `stage` and 
`stage` has one_to_many association with `task` but i am not able to pass `project_id` while importing data in stage table. same i want to do with `task` table has a column `stage_id`.

stage.rb

```
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy

  def self.import(file, project_id)
    accessible_attributes = ['task_name','planned_start_date', 'planned_end_date', 'actual_start_date', 'actual_end_date']


    spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    i = 2
    last_row = spreadsheet.last_row

    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
        row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
       if row['id'].is_a?(Integer) == true
        stage = Stage.new
        stage.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
        #stage.attributes = row.to_hash.merge(project_id: project_id).slice(*accessible_attributes) -> i tried this line also
        stage.save!


       elsif row['id'].to_s.split('').count == 3
        task = Task.new
        task.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
        task.save!
      end
    end
end
```

stage_controller.rb

```
  def import
    Stage.import(params[:file], params[:project_id])
    redirect_to project_path(@project), notice:"Projects imported. "
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h2>Import Project Activities</h2>

<%= form_tag import_project_stages_path(@project), multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import", :class=>"button warning" %>
<%end %>
```

what i tried-
after stage.save line i added-

```
Stage.update_all(project_id: 1) # this worked 
Stage.update_all(project_id: project_id) # this doesn't worked i don;t know why project_id is not accessible here.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like `stage.project_id = project_id` before save

Comment: no it's not working, project_id still goes nil to stage table

Comment: are you receiving the correct value inside your import method or is it going nil?

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear that you create a `project` before, or after passing its id to the method.
you just have to check if there is a project with that `project_id` in your database, if not create one.
Also, `params[:project_id]` may not work due to an error while getting it from the `params` or, if it is not sent (sent as `nil`), and if it is not there, you must create a new one or just `return` from the method.
Also, you can return the `stage`(s) and assign it to a `project` in the controller.